# PHP and BitTorrents

Tags: php, bittorrent

How can I read / decode a .torrent file with PHP?

Do I need any specific library to decode such files or is it something simpler?

Comment: I don't know of any library but if you're forced to write one yourself knowledge of the spec may help: http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification. Specifically the section on 'Metainfo File Structure'

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Module for reading torrent files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167206/php-module-for-reading-torrent-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific library to decode .torrent files, also see [File_Bittorrent2](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Bittorrent2), from the [PEAR library](http://pear.php.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [torrentflux](http://www.torrentflux.com/). Its an open source bit torrent client. The code in /html/BDecode.php deals with decoding .torrent files.