# Simple torrent system in PHP?

Tags: php, download, bittorrent

I need to be able to manage some torrent downloads on my server with some good old php, basically i would upload the .torrent file, and would like the php script to download the torrent file(s) in the torrent, and zip them. and while its doing this, have a page that could output the progress and statistics... im not even sure where to start!

**Summary**

1. Upload .torrent file
2. Have php download the files in the torrent
3. Have a method to keep track of the progress

Any help would be greatly appriciated :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, check out the answers on [PHP Module for reading torrent files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167206/php-module-for-reading-torrent-files)

Particularly Eran's answer, where he links to http://sourceforge.net/projects/torrentflux/. I've never used it, so I can't vouch for it or anything, but it looks like you could install it and get what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should not invent the wheel and use, for example, [RTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTorrent) as a backend and write a web interface for it as a frontend using php.

Answer (score 2):

What you want sounds awfully like the integrated web based control panels of many torrent clients. Some of them provide RPC capabilities over HTTP with XML. Maybe you can treat the torrent client as a web service and use PHP as a front end for it.